# I can't edit marker text in Logic Pro X

Tags: software, logic-pro

In Logic Pro X, I occasionally have a problem editing marker text.

In the Marker tab in the List views,

[image]

When I click the "Edit" button, I can only type one character. After that, the text box immediately becomes un-editable, and any more keypresses I make are interpreted as keyboard shortcuts. In order to write anything, I have to click the edit button, type a single character, click the edit button again, and repeat until finished. I only have this problem sometimes - other times, the text box works as I expect it to, remaining active until I finish and click the "Done" button.

How can I get Logic Pro X to behave the way I expect it to when I'm having problems editing marker text?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem, and while I can't provide a permanent solution to it I can tell you what will avoid that behavior. Make sure that the particular marker you want to edit is selected in the marker bar above the track before you go to edit the text. This works for me in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Enable 'Show/Hide Global Tracks'
[image: Show/Hide Global Tracks]

Right Click and select 'Marker' if it's not already in the dropdown
[image: Right Click and select 'Marker']

Now Double Click on the marker you want to rename
[image: Double Click on the marker]

works every time for me.

P.S : LPX 10.3.2